# How to avoid calling observe method twice?

Tags: angular

The API call is implemented on `ngOnInit` as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.applicationObs = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        filter((params) => params.has('id')),
        switchMap((params) => this.applicationService.getApplicationDetails(params.get('id'))),
        map((data: ApplicationResponse) => data),
    );

    this.applicationObsSubscription = this.applicationObs.subscribe((response) => {
        const fabricaSidebar = fabricApplicationSidebarMenu(response.application);
        this.sidebarSections = fabricaSidebar.getSidebarMenuItems();
    });
}
```

Then in template I use `async` to get data:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="applicationObs | async as app; else loading">
```

Problem is that it calls twice, one for `async`, another time when `subscribe` is called.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't subscribe, instead do that in `tap` operator

Comment: Use tap after map operator?

Comment: Before filter I would say. Also your map operator is doing nothing.

Comment: Put tap After switch?

Comment: Oh sorry, you were right. It should go after map, yeah

Comment: After switch, right> bercause I need a reponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve the issue. Seeing that you have a `map` at the end of the operator chain, you could assign the `sidebarSections` inside it instead of a separate subscription. Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.applicationObs = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    filter((params) => params.has('id')),
    switchMap((params) => this.applicationService.getApplicationDetails(params.get('id'))),
    map((data: ApplicationResponse) => {
      this.sidebarSections = this.fabricApplicationSidebarMenu(data.application).getSidebarMenuItems();
      return data;
    })
  );
}
```

If you aren't returning a transformed variable from the `map`, you could also use the `tap` operator instead without the `return` statement.

With this, it is also important to remember the subscription is only triggered (and the variable is assigned) when the associated DOM element with the `async` pipe is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use additional variable

```
applicationObs$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

ngOnInit() {
    this.applicationObs = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        filter((params) => params.has('id')),
        switchMap((params) => this.applicationService.getApplicationDetails(params.get('id'))),
        tap((data: ApplicationResponse) => this.applicationObs$.next(data)),
    )
    .subscribe((response) => {
        const fabricaSidebar = fabricApplicationSidebarMenu(response.application);
        this.sidebarSections = fabricaSidebar.getSidebarMenuItems();
    })
}

<ng-container *ngIf="applicationObs$ | async as app; else loading">
```